# CSS Structure For This

Tags: html, css

The situation is like this:

```
<div id="HTML5" class="widget HTML">
  <div class="widget content">
```

I want to apply a left padding of 6px to the content of this particular HTML5 widget which won't be applicable to other  HTML widgets (HTML1, 2, 3 or 4)

What would the css be like?

Would it be :

```
div#HTML5.widgetHTML.widget content {
   padding-left: 6px;
}
```

Please correct! 
 Thank you.

Comment: Please use proper formatting so that it would be easier for all of us to help you on your problem.

Comment: Are you asking how CSS selectors work? If so, and I don't mean to offend, you should really go and read up on some basics first. Also, please format your question properly. You could use a jsfiddle (there is a button in the editor to include one right here in your question).

Comment: I tried to format my code according to the guidelines. I don't know where I went wrong. I selected the code, gave 4 spaces and pressed ctrl+k.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are trying to modify the styles of your Blogger template. This is what you are looking for, it will give a left padding to the content section of your #HTML5 widget.

```
#HTML5 .content {
  padding-left: 6px;
}
```

Make sure you add the above code inside the `<style>` tag.

Cheers!